# Overflow hidden with carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a an infinite looping carousel with 2 images rendering at a time. I currently have a div that is the slider. inside of it I have a `<ul>` and inside of that i have five `<li>`. Now I set the wide of the slider to be the width of the screen and the height is set to 1080. I want the overflowing items in the list to be hidden.

For some reason, they are not being hidden, but rather just sticking to the bottom of the carousel image. How can I get them to actually hide?

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#app {
    height: 1080px;
    width: 100%;
}

#slider {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.slides {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.slide {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 49.3%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 5px;
    background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000');
}

#title {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    margin-top: 150px;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 4px solid white;
}

#caption {
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    margin-top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <!-- this crousel will be able to look infinitiey. I will do this by assigning
        a set of images a number or id value. Once the user has cycled to the last
        image, it will reset the cycle and start from the beginning. 
        Point 1 => image 1 and 2
        Point 2 => image 2 and 3
        Point 3 => image 3 and 4
        Point 4 => image 4 and 5
        Cycle Reset -->
        <button id="previous" onclick="previousItem()"><</button>
        <div id="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li class="slide 0">
                    <div>
                        <span id="title">Vega</span>
                        <span id="caption">Vega is one of the leading global plant-based nutrition companies.</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="slide 1">
                    <div>
                        <span id="title">EightSleep</span>
                        <span id="caption">Eight has developed the world\'s first smart mattress.</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="slide 2">
                    <div>
                        <span id="title">The Hundereds.com</span>
                        <span id="caption">The Hundereds Shopify Plus eCommerse site features a 100% custom and seamless Wordpress integraion.</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="slide 3">
                    <div >
                        <span id="title">PRG Nation</span>
                        <span id="caption">InnerSelf Technologies hopes to create4 a PRG Nation, built around their new bio-stimulant and monitoring system.</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="slide 4">
                    <div>
                        <span id="title">Qualo.com</span>
                        <span id="caption">Immerseive, highly-branded, and customer-focused shopping experience.</span>
                    </div>
                </<body>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- this crousel will be able to look infinitiey. I will do this by assigning
a set of images a number or id value. Once the user has cycled to the last
image, it will reset the cycle and start from the beginning. 
Point 1 => image 1 and 2
Point 2 => image 2 and 3
Point 3 => image 3 and 4
Point 4 => image 4 and 5
Cycle Reset -->
    <button id="previous" onclick="previousItem()"><</button>
      <div id="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
          <li class="slide 0">
            <div>
              <span id="title">Vega</span>
              <span id="caption">Vega is one of the leading global plant-based nutrition companies.</span>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="slide 1">
            <div>
              <span id="title">EightSleep</span>
              <span id="caption">Eight has developed the world\'s first smart mattress.</span>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="slide 2">
            <div>
              <span id="title">The Hundereds.com</span>
              <span id="caption">The Hundereds Shopify Plus eCommerse site features a 100% custom and seamless Wordpress integraion.</span>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="slide 3">
            <div >
              <span id="title">PRG Nation</span>
              <span id="caption">InnerSelf Technologies hopes to create4 a PRG Nation, built around their new bio-stimulant and monitoring system.</span>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="slide 4">
            <div>
              <span id="title">Qualo.com</span>
              <span id="caption">Immerseive, highly-branded, and customer-focused shopping experience.</span>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <button id="next" onclick="nextItem()">></button>
      </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="bundle.js"></script> -->
    </body>li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button id="next" onclick="nextItem()">></button>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="bundle.js"></script> -->
</body>
```

I can't seem to get it working. I want them to stack next to each other  horizontally and just move them right to left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.slide > div {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: thank you. Another question. using `jquery`... do you know how I can move the list items over 500 px to from right to left